# Actual version of iOS I need from, to publish new app to Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Where can I find information which actual version of iOS I need for publishing new app to AppStore?

I mean where in apple guide lines, I can see something like this:
"For now when you publishing your app, supporting version of iOS must start from iOS 9" or something like this.

Comment: What is your concrete question? You should always build against the latest SDK, and you can chose your deployment target (minimum OS version) quite freely. And it will/should then run on any newer platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple usually posts this on the developer news feed: https://developer.apple.com/news/

Unfortunately it seems that they delete old posts, but you can find the last one from February 2015 over at [9to5mac.com](http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/20/apple-to-require-ios-apps-and-updates-to-use-ios-8-sdk-and-include-64-bit-support-from-february-2015/).

> “Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store
>   must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included
>   in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend
>   using the default Xcode build setting of ‘Standard architectures’ to
>   build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.”

Comment: It states what the minimum Base SDK should be but not what the minimum Deployment Target can be. While the OP's question isn't too clear, the words *"must start from"* kind of imply the question is about the Deployment Target, not the Base SDK.